# Tokenising text using boost regex

Tags: c++, regex, pcre, boost-regex

I forget regular expressions faster then my mothers birthday. It is a major PITA. Anyhow I wanted a RE for parsing the HTTP response status line and have the sub-elements properly captured. I got this working :

```
  const boost::regex status_line("HTTP/(\\d+?)\\.(\\d+?) (\\d+?) (.*)\r\n");
  std::string status_test1("HTTP/1.1 200 hassan ali\r\n");

  boost::smatch what;
  std::cout << regex_match(status_test1,what, status_line, boost::match_extra) << std::endl;
  std::cout << what.size() << std::endl;

  BOOST_FOREACH(std::string s, what)
  {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }
```

The 4th capture group is what I was fussing about, particularly tokenising the words. But I don't need it so my job is done. However, I'd still like to know how to tokenise a space seperated sentence that ends with a '\0' which results in a vector/array of stripped words.

I can't get the following fragment to work

```
  const boost::regex sentence_re("(.+?)( (.+?))*");
  boost::smatch sentence_what;
  std::string sentence("hassan ali syed ");

  std::cout << boost::regex_match(sentence,sentence_what,sentence_re, boost::match_extra) << std::endl;

  BOOST_FOREACH(std::string s, sentence_what)
  {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }
```

it shouldn't match `"hassan ali syed "`, but it should match `"hassan ali syed"`, and the capture group should output `hassan` `ali` `syed` (with newlines), but it outputs `hassan` `syed` `syed` (note, the space in the third syed`<space>syed`. **I suppose capture groups can't deal with recursive entities ?**

So, is there a clean way for specifying a tokenising task in PCRE syntax, that results in a clean token vector (without repetition --i.e., I don't want the nested group to try and strip the whitespace).

I know this isn't the right tool for the job, spirit / lexx or boost::tokenise is best, and I know it isn't the right way to go about it. in .net when doing screen scraping I'd find tokens in bodies of text by repeatedly applying a regular expression to the body till it ran out of tokens.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a similar question, [Capturing repeating subpatterns in Python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764930/capturing-repeating-subpatterns-in-python-regex).

If the number of space-separated words is limited to some maximum number of tokens, then you can just tack on a whole bunch of extra subpatterns, somewhat like:

```
"HTTP/(\\d+?)\\.(\\d+?) (\\d+?) ([^ ]+\s)?([^ ]+\s)?([^ ]+\s)?([^ ]+\s)?\n\r"
```

Which is of course, horrible.

If you wanted a nested group, I don't *think* this can be done without "repeated subpattern" support in your regexp implementation (see Python's nonstandard `regex` module as used in the linked question.) You are almost certainly better off doing this with elementary string functions - your local equivalent of `string.split()`.

Comment: Note: I am not a C++ or Boost::regexp user.

Answer (score 0):

Boost might be able to do recursive groupings, not sure. I lean towards that it can't.
I only know of .NET that can do that.

You can design a single regex with two parts. First part captures specific groups, the second captures in a single group all the rest. You can then do another recursive regex on the second part captured.

Something like this:
`(specific)(part)(to)(capture)(all the remaining text)`

Then do a while( /(part)/ ) regex on the previous remaining text capture.

Here's how you could do it in boost -

```
const string status = "HTTP/1.1 200 hassan ali\r\n";

boost::regex rx_sentence ( "HTTP/(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*([^\\s]+(?:\\s+[^\\s]+)*)?.*" );
boost::regex rx_token ( "[^\\s]+" );

if ( boost::regex_match( status, what, rx_sentence) )
{
    std::cout << "\nMatched:\n-----------------\n" << "'" << what[0] << "'" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nStatus (match groups):\n-----------------" << std::endl;
    for (int i=1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " = '" << what[i] << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "\nTokens (search of group 4):\n-----------------" << std::endl;
    const string token_str = what[4];

    std::string::const_iterator start = token_str.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end   = token_str.end();

    while ( boost::regex_search(start, end, what, rx_token) )
    {
        string token(what[0].first, what[0].second);
        cout << "'" << token << "'" << endl;
        start = what[0].second;
    }
}
else
    std::cout << "Didn't match" << std::endl;
```