# How can I repeat a capturing group one or more time and extract matches

Tags: python, regex

Is it possibile with one regex to validate this string and extract all names :

Input :

```
daz.Da zD.{Azd} .{AZDza}; D
name:{franck}{steve}{louis}
zefzef{z'f'z} fze fzef zef
```

ouptut :

```python
[0] "franck"
[1] "steve"
[2] "louis"
```

Here is what I got : `name:(?:{(.*?)})` but I don't know how to repeat (one or more) this expression `(?:{(.*?)})` to extract all name after `name:`.

**I don't want to use [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) python package that supports repeated capturing groups.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing repeating subpatterns in Python regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764930/capturing-repeating-subpatterns-in-python-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the matches by using the `\G` anchor with [Python regex package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

> It matches at the position where each search started/continued

```
(?:name:|\G(?!^)){([^}]+)}
```

- `(?:name:|\G(?!^))` first part: Match `name:` literally `|\G` or continue where the last match ended, `(?!^)` [but not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at start.
- `{([^}]+)}` second part: Capture [non](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated)`}` inside `{`...`}` to $1 glued to successfull previous match.

Use with `regex.findall`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eR6pQ5/1)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted! :)

Comment: With the regex package you can do much simpler, since it is able to store results of a repeated capture group. You can use this simple pattern with the `search` method: `name:(?:{([^}]+)})+` and use `m.captures(1)` to obtain the list of results.

Answer (score 1):

Not with a single regex but you may do like this,

```
>>> s = '''daz.Da zD.{Azd} .{AZDza}; D
name:{franck}{steve}{louis}
zefzef{z'f'z} fze fzef zef'''
>>> [j for i in re.findall(r'(?m)^name:(.*)', s) for j in re.findall(r'\{([^}]*)\}', i)]
['franck', 'steve', 'louis']
```

This would print all the names present inside the curly barces from the line which starts with `name:`

or

Use `startswith`

```
>>> s = '''daz.Da zD.{Azd} .{AZDza}; D
name:{franck}{steve}{louis}
zefzef{z'f'z} fze fzef zef'''.splitlines()
>>> [j for line in s  for j in re.findall(r'\{([^}]*)\}', line) if line.startswith('name')]
['franck', 'steve', 'louis']
```