# How to write regular expression to find multiple strings in Python

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have a string like

```
"look[+3],panel button layout[+3],feature[+2]it 's very sleek looking with a very good front panel button layout , and it has a great feature set . "
```

"look[+3]" means that the sentence talks about certain aspect of an item, and [+3] means it is a positive review with score 3.(This is actually from Amazon review dataset.)

I would like to split it like

```
X: "it 's very sleek looking with a very good front panel button layout , and it has a great feature set ."

Y: [("look", 3), ("panel button layout", 3), ("feature", 2)]
```

Comment: Um, wouldn't it be possible to scrape the reviews more properly so you won't need a regex to extract information?

Comment: Are you sure there is not `,` after `feature[+2]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to capture everything after the beginning of the string or a comma, until `[` and extracting the number after the `[+`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "look[+3],panel button layout[+3],feature[+2]it 's very sleek looking with a very good front panel button layout , and it has a great feature set . "
>>> re.findall(r"(?:^|,)(.*?)\[\+?(\-?\d+)\]", s)
[('look', '3'), ('panel button layout', '3'), ('feature', '2')]
>>>
>>> s = "darn diopter adjustment dial[-1]"
>>> re.findall(r"(?:^|,)(.*?)\[\+?(\-?\d+)\]", s)                                                            
[('darn diopter adjustment dial', '-1')]
```

where:

- `(?:^|,)` is a non-capturing group that would either match the beginning of a string or a comma
- `(.*?)` is a *non-greedy* match for any character any number of times
- `\[\+?(\-?\d+)\]` would match an opening `[` followed by an optional `+` followed by a capturing group that would capture one or more digits (with an optional `-` at the beginning), followed by a closing `]`

Comment: I think `re.finditer()` would work better to answer the other part of the question (`X: "It's …"), but `re.sub()` would probably work just as well.

Comment: `darn diopter adjustment dial[-1]##the reason i rated it a four is because of that darn diopter adjustment dial. its very small and hard to turn so you can 't get an accurate adjustment ( for those of you who do n't know what a diopter adjustment is , it is to adjust the focus of the viewfinder to your eyesight . ) `
`[]` I find it not working in this case.

Comment: Where did that `##` come from?

Comment: You can ignore that.

Comment: @Vicky please check the update now. It handles both +  and - before the digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall('(.*\[\+\d+\],?)', s)` to get your desired `Y` output.

Answer (score -1):

[try this regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/pO8zZ4/1):

```
([^\]]+[[^\]])+(.*)
```

your key/val pairs are in $1, the summary in $2.

EDIT: while `re` doesn't support multiple matches per group (only last capture is available), [the new `regex` module does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764930/capturing-repeating-subpatterns-in-python-regex):

```
>>> m = regex.search(r"([^\]]+[[^\]])+(.*)", "look[+3],panel button layout[+3],feature[+2]it 's very sleek looking with a very good front panel button layout , and it has a great feature set . ")
>>> m.group(1)
',feature[+2]'
>>> m.captures(1)
['look[+3]', ',panel button layout[+3]', ',feature[+2]']
>>> m.group(2)
"it's very sleek looking with a very good front panel button layout , and it has a great feature set . "
```

Comment: Did you look at the link you posted? The expression only finds the last key.

Comment: I get `(',feature[+2]', "it 's very sleek looking with a very good front panel button layout , and it has a great feature set . ")`.  Am I not doing it right?  I've tried several `re` functions, but I can't seem to get the right output with that regex.

Comment: python supports those match groups, the online tool doesn't - it works.

Comment: Then please post the proper invocation to extract `[("look", 3), ("panel button layout", 3), ("feature", 2)]`.