# Why does matching the following regular expressions result in these groups?

Tags: python, regex

```
    import re
    m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
    n= m.groups()
```

why in this case does m only contain 'c',as [abc] can be any character 'a', 'b' or 'c' and '+' indicates this can be repeated shouldn't 'a', 'b' and 'c' all be placed in groups?

Comment: Yes, a capturing group is repeated, but the value it stores will only the one captured at the last iteration.

Comment: Usually sth. like `(outergroup(?:innergroup)+)` is a workaround.

Comment: if u do `([abc]+)` u get your abc else its rewriting the same group id every time resulting in group 0 = a, group 0 = b, group 0 = c giving c as a end result

Comment: Just install the PyPi regex module and enjoy the `.captures`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9765390/3832970.