# Python - odd regex matching with + / * on group

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> src = '  pkg.subpkg.submod.thing  pkg2.subpkg.submod.thing  '
>>> re.search(r'\s*(\w+\.)+', src).groups()
('submod.',)
```

This regex seems to put everything which is not space into a/the group - nothing to be lost before stop of regex match.

Why is just the **last** "+" repetition found in the group here - and not `('pkg.subpkg.submod.',)`?

Or `('pkg.',)` - early stop because no real repetition - no "loss of information" in another sense?

(I needed to use another `(?:...)` like `r'\s((?:\w+\.)+)'`)

Even more strange:

```
>>> src = '  pkg.subpkg.submod.thing  pkg2.subpkg.submod.thing  '
>>> re.search(r'\s(\w+\.)*', src).groups()
(None,)
```

---

Edit: the "more strange" is actually "less strange" as @Avinash Raj pointed out, because - unlike intended - the match simply ends before the group; So

```
>>> re.search(r'\s+(\w+\.)*', '  pkg.subpkg.submod.thing').groups()
('submod.',)
```

.. then produces the same questioned behavior than "+" : just last repetition - things before seeming lost...

Comment: See [Capturing repeating subpatterns in Python regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764930/capturing-repeating-subpatterns-in-python-regex).

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain the even more strange part..

```
src = '  pkg.subpkg.submod.thing  pkg2.subpkg.submod.thing  '
```

`re.search` stops matching once it finds a first match. So,

`r'\s(\w+\.)*'` would match the first space character (*`*` repeats the previous pattern zero or more times*), since there is no match for `(\w+\.)*` after the first space, [`groups()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) function on searchObj returns `None` and `group` on searchObj should return the space that is the first space.

Comment: Oh, yes - in a hurry I intended something like `>>> re.search(r'\s(\w+\.)*', ' pkg.subpkg.submod.thing').groups()
('submod.',)`  (the group actually gets something) which then yields the same thing as "+"

Comment: @kxr why they used another capturing group is, to capture the repeated groups. take this example `(a)+` in the input string `aaa` should match all the `a`'s but capture only the last `a` because you're repating the `a` as-well as the capturing group one or more times. Actually you have to use the plus inside the capturing group `(a+)` . Hope you get cleared..

Comment: `a`  from  `(a)+`  and consuming up to the last possible `a` is more understandable because of identical repetitions - like in `re.search(r'(a)(\1)', 'aaabb').groups()`. But here there seems to be sort of "information loss"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, why it is strange for you. What do you expect?

In the documentation you find the following:

*re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern ...*

```
re.search(r'\s*(\w+\.)+', src).groups()
```

in your search string you have only one group: **(\w+.)**
Because it is greedy by default all the **pkg.subpkg.** is eaten before you find **submod.**, this is the last that is filled, that the string matches.

your second try doesn't match, cause there is not even 1 group nessesary to fulfil the Statement, so all 3 parts are eaten and inside the Group you find nothing.

Do you look for this?

```
re.search(r'\s*((\w+\.)+)', src).groups()[0]
```

Try out the following to understand it better:

```
re.search(r'\s*((\w+\.)*)(\w+\.)*', 'a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i').groups()
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine to match the complete string '  pkg.subpkg.submod.thing  pkg2.subpkg.submod.thing  '

```
(\s*(\w+[.\s])+)+
```

In case you want the output '  pkg.subpkg.submod.thing  ' then use this

```
\s*(\w+[.\s])+
```

Comment: should help nevertheless, no? Since he seemed to be struggling with 2 tries