# non-capturing parenthesis with lookbehind and lookahead - Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

So I want to capture the indices in a string like this:

```
 "Something bad happened! @ data[u'string_1'][u'string_2']['u2'][0]"
```

I want to capture the strings `string_1`, `string_2`, `u2`, and `0`.

I was able to do this using the following regex:

```
re.findall("("
           "((?<=\[u')|(?<=\['))" # Begins with [u' or ['
           "[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+" # Followed by any letters, numbers, _'s, or -'s
           "(?='\])" # Ending with ']
           ")"
           "|" # OR
           "("
           "(?<=\[)" # Begins with [
           "[0-9]+" # Followed by any numbers
           "(?=\])" # Endging with ]
           ")", message)
```

Problem is the result will include tuples with empty strings, as such:

```
[('string_1', '', ''), ('string_2', '', ''), ('u2', '', ''), ('', '', '0')]
```

Now I can easily filter out the empty strings from the result, but I would like to prevent them from appearing in the first place.

I believe that the reason for this is due to my capture groups. I tried to use `?:` in those group, but then my results were completely gone.

This is how I had attempted to do it:

```
re.findall("(?:"
           "((?<=\[u')|(?<=\['))" # Begins with [u' or ['
           "[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+" # Followed by any letters, numbers, _'s, or -'s
           "(?='\])" # Ending with ']
           ")"
           "|" # OR
           "(?:"
           "(?<=\[)" # Begins with [
           "[0-9]+" # Followed by any numbers
           "(?=\])" # Endging with ]
           ")", message)
```

That results in the following output:

```
['', '', '', '']
```

I'm assuming the issue is due to me using lookbehinds along with the non-capturing groups. Any ideas on whether this is possible to do in Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regex.

```
(?<=\[)u?'?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(?='?\])
```

See demo .

https://regex101.com/r/SA6shx/1

Comment: That will end up capturing the `u'`. I know you're probably going to say that I can use `re.search` and use the `groups`, but groups only capture the very last match of the sub-pattern. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9765390

Comment: My apologies. This works. Now I'm wondering why it's not grabbing the `u'`

Comment: @Mo2 re.findall only gives group if it has one...if not then whole match

Comment: I see. TIL. Thank you. I can't remove the downvote unless the answer is edited. It won't let me.

Comment: Done. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`(?<=\[)(?:[^'\]]*')?([^'\]]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nH4BfE/3) or `\[(?:[^'\]]*')?([^'\]]+)`

**Python code**:

```
def Years(text):
        return re.findall(r'(?<=\[)(?:[^\'\]]*\')?([^\'\]]+)', text)

print(Years('Something bad happened! @ data[u\'string_1\'][u\'string_2\'][\'u2\'][0]'))
```

Output:

```
['string_1', 'string_2', 'u2', '0']
```