# Python regex back reference match all

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use python regex back reference to match all instances for the first group match, but it is stopping at the first match. How can i match all the occurrences? For example:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.open('POST', 'http://example.com', false);
req.send(null)
```

My first group match is `req`, and then if `req` is found, I am trying to match `req.open` and `req.send`, but I am only getting a match on `req.open`.

The pattern I am using is

```
([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)\s?=\s?new XMLHttpRequest.+?(\1\.((open|send)\(.+?\)))
```

[Here is the regex101](https://regex101.com/r/U69Na3/1)

Comment: `([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)\s?=\s?new XMLHttpRequest(?:.+?(\1\.((open|send)\(.+?\))))+`? See https://regex101.com/r/VlWVgy/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in your regex101, it is only matching `req.send`. I would like to match both `req.send` and `req.open`

Comment: So you want to access all captures of the repeated capturing groups. The regex  shared works as you need, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9765390/3832970) how. Use it with PyPi regex module and access the `.captures` of the necessary group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is not a duplicate! The issue mentioned is not the same. one is for findall, but in this case, findall doesnt solve the need

Comment: `findall` won't help. You need to wrap the repeated part with a non-capturing group  - see my pattern - then access that group `.captures` after running the regex with `regex.finditer`. See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9765390/3832970)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please reopen the post. I have tried that link that you posted, and just like in regex101 examples, it is only matching on the `req.send` and not both req.send and req.open. The issue are your relating to this SO post is not the same. When I run the python code from the reference post, I am only getting `('req', 'req.send(null)', 'send(null)', 'send')` which does not solve the original question

Comment: That solution [works very well](https://rextester.com/VYEY25873), why reopen?

Comment: Ah. i failed to notice the use of the `regex` lib vs stdlib `re`. Thanks