# Ansible replace or lineinfile?

Tags: regex, sed, ansible

All,

I have been trying to figure something out all day, i got ot working with the shell module and sed but cant do it with a more native way such as replace or lineinfile. This is what i am trying to do:

I have a file that has a few lines and some lines start with a different string but others with the same which are the ones i want to edit, then all the lines at some point have a particular string and i want to edit this string only on the lines that start with that particular string.

Here is a more visual example:

The file by the way is /etc/fstab and looks something like this

```
Aaaaa:/mount1  /mountpoint1 nfs mount-options 0 0
Aaaaa:/mount2  /mountpoint4 nfs mount-options 0 0
Bbbbbn:/mount1  /mountpoin9  nfs mount-options 0 0
```

As you can see in this example the mount options which is what I want to change are identical however I want to edit only the ones in lines that start with aaaa for example.

Any clues how to do this with a module like replace or lineinfile and not sed using the shell?

Thanks

UPDATE:
Let me clarify that the stuff after aaaaa: until nfs mount-options 0 0 could be anything, as the mount folders and mount points on the server could be anything.
Also this is how I got it to work using the shell module, still looking for a more native module instead of shell:

```
  - name: Inserting new mounting options
    shell: sed -i '/^aaaaa/ s/mount-options/new-mount-options/g' /etc/fstab
```

In the above example I successfully target lines starting with aaaaa and replace the mount-options to different ones while keeping the 0 0 at this end.

Comment: try to use native ansible mount resource ansible-doc mount

Comment: I am not trying to mount anything, I am trying to edit a line particular line in the file, lets forget that the file is /etc/fstab, i just want to edit those lines that start with a certain word in them and not the others.

Comment: Can you also add the working shell module in your question? I am a bit confused about what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

The module *replace* fits the use case better. See the example below. For example, let's

- set `dump fsck` to `1 1` where lines begin with `Aaaaa`
- set `fstype` to `ext4` where lines begin with `Bbbbbn`

The task below

```yaml
- replace:
    path: /scratch/fstab
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  loop:
    - regexp: '^Aaaaa(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)(.*)$'
      replace: 'Aaaaa\1 \2 \3 \4 1 1'
    - regexp: '^Bbbbbn(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)(.*)$'
      replace: 'Bbbbbn\1 \2 ext4 \4 \5 \6'
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat fstab
Aaaaa:/mount1 /mountpoint1 nfs mount-options 1 1
Aaaaa:/mount2 /mountpoint4 nfs mount-options 1 1
Bbbbbn:/mount1 /mountpoin9 ext4 mount-options 0 0
```

---

Note: The regex is cumbersome. I can't get working [Capturing repeating subpatterns in Python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764930/capturing-repeating-subpatterns-in-python-regex).

---

**Update**

Update fstab in a systemic way if you can install [jc](https://pypi.org/project/jc/). For example, given the file for testing

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/fstab 
Aaaaa:/mount1  /mountpoint1 nfs mount-options 0 0
Aaaaa:/mount2  /mountpoint4 nfs mount-options 0 0
Bbbbbn:/mount1  /mountpoin9  nfs mount-options 0 0
```

declare the path

```yaml
  fstab_path: /tmp/fstab
```

and fetch the file to the controller

```yaml
    - fetch:
        src: "{{ fstab_path }}"
        dest: /tmp/ansible/fstab/
```

Declare the local path on the controller

```yaml
  fstab_local: "/tmp/ansible/fstab/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ fstab_path }}"
```

and parse the file

```yaml
  fstab: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'cat ' ~ fstab_local ~ ' | jc --fstab') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fstab:
  - fs_file: /mountpoint1
    fs_freq: 0
    fs_mntops: mount-options
    fs_passno: 0
    fs_spec: Aaaaa:/mount1
    fs_vfstype: nfs
  - fs_file: /mountpoint4
    fs_freq: 0
    fs_mntops: mount-options
    fs_passno: 0
    fs_spec: Aaaaa:/mount2
    fs_vfstype: nfs
  - fs_file: /mountpoin9
    fs_freq: 0
    fs_mntops: mount-options
    fs_passno: 0
    fs_spec: Bbbbbn:/mount1
    fs_vfstype: nfs
```

Declare what you want to update

```yaml
    fstab_update:
      fs_spec: Aaaaa
      fs_mntops: new-mount-options
```

and update the fstab

```yaml
    fstab_new: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in fstab %}
      {% if i.fs_spec is search(fstab_update.fs_spec) %}
      - {{ i|combine({'fs_mntops': fstab_update.fs_mntops}) }}
      {% else %}
      - {{ i }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in fstab_new %}
          {{ fstab_labels|map('extract', i)|join(' ') }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    Aaaaa:/mount1 /mountpoint1 nfs new-mount-options 0 0
    Aaaaa:/mount2 /mountpoint4 nfs new-mount-options 0 0
    Bbbbbn:/mount1 /mountpoin9 nfs mount-options 0 0
```

Update the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ fstab_path }}"
        content: |
          {% for i in fstab_new %}
          {{ fstab_labels|map('extract', i)|join(' ') }}
          {% endfor %}
```

**Example of a complete playbook for testing**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    fstab_path: /tmp/fstab
    fstab_local: "/tmp/ansible/fstab/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ fstab_path }}"
    fstab: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'cat ' ~ fstab_local ~ ' | jc --fstab') }}"

    fstab_labels: [fs_spec, fs_file, fs_vfstype, fs_mntops, fs_freq, fs_passno]
    fstab_update:
      fs_spec: Aaaaa
      fs_mntops: new-mount-options

    fstab_new: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in fstab %}
      {% if i.fs_spec is search(fstab_update.fs_spec) %}
      - {{ i|combine({'fs_mntops': fstab_update.fs_mntops}) }}
      {% else %}
      - {{ i }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - fetch:
        src: "{{ fstab_path }}"
        dest: /tmp/ansible/fstab/

    - debug:
        var: fstab

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in fstab_new %}
          {{ fstab_labels|map('extract', i)|join(' ') }}
          {% endfor %}

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ fstab_path }}"
        content: |
          {% for i in fstab_new %}
          {{ fstab_labels|map('extract', i)|join(' ') }}
          {% endfor %}
      when: not dry_run|d(true)|bool
```

Comment: I am a little lost at your regex there, i will try to take it apart and see if it can work for me

Comment: The regex comprises 7 groups; 6x  (\S+) non-whitespace chars, and 1x (.*) any chars separated by at least one whitespace \s+. These 6 groups correspond to the fields in fstab. It can be easily changed. Put any regex instead of a group. For example to select fstype `nfs` use '^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(nfs)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)(.*)$'

Comment: Ah this might help with what i am trying to do becase i just found that the mount options are different everytime so i need to target groups instead. I will give it a go.