# Grouping what already grouped in regex

Tags: python, regex, logging, logparser

Regex -

```
(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\dZ)\s+(INFO|WARN|DEBUG|ERROR|FATAL|TRACE)\s+(.*?\s+.*?)(.*?)\-\s+(.*?)\s+(?:(\[?.*?\])?)(.*)
```

Logs -

```
2019-11-14T04:25:00.123Z  WARN http-nio-127.0.0.1-7440-exec-127 CorfuCompileProxy - accessInner: Encountered a trim exception while accessing version 120383907 on attempt 0
2019-11-14T04:23:08.700Z  INFO RpcManagerRequestCleanupTimer RpcManager - SYSTEM [nsx@6876 comp="nsx-manager" level="INFO" subcomp="manager"] Rpc response not received for application FabricStats request com.vmware.nsx.management.agg.messaging.AggService$ClientDataRequestMsg from client 8ac94189-d611-4eb3-9b93-c3c3a8e3d36a with correlation id 287e690e-0a47-4459-a0bb-be36fe439068 in 432000000 msec.
2019-11-14T04:24:04.072Z  INFO MessagingObjectFactoryImpl-4-2 ExporterLastAckServiceImpl - - [nsx@6876 comp="nsx-manager" level="INFO" subcomp="manager"] Found exporter with elaId = Node#a3844284-e626-11e9-a87b-005056bcc0c6#AggSvc-L2-Bridging, returning lastAck = 16507 
2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z  INFO ActivityEventRecovery-1 ActivityCacheManager - - [nsx@6876 comp="nsx-manager" level="INFO" subcomp="manager"] Handling activity 92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0 completion event for 1 
2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z  DEBUG ActivityEventRecovery-1 ActivityCacheManager - - [nsx@6876 comp="nsx-manager" level="INFO" subcomp="manager"] Handling activity 92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0 completion event for 1
```

In the above logs, I need to make a group 8 where id's of group 7 will get included.
id's are `.*-.*-.*-.*-.*`

link - https://regex101.com/r/LJnVrS/98

Comment: What are group 8 and group 7? what are the expected results?

Comment: It sounds as if you wanted a [repeated capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764930/capturing-repeating-subpatterns-in-python-regex). Can't you extract what you need from Group 7 with another `re.findall`? Not sure what you need, so just guessing, `re.findall(r'-([^-\s]+)', match.group(7))`?

Comment: my message group for 2nd log is  
Group(7) - ` Rpc response not received for application FabricStats request com.vmware.nsx.management.agg.messaging.AggService$ClientDataRequestMsg from client 8ac94189-d611-4eb3-9b93-c3c3a8e3d36a with correlation id 287e690e-0a47-4459-a0bb-be36fe439068 in 432000000 msec.`

Now I need Group(8) which should have array of two id's - 
Group(8) - `8ac94189-d611-4eb3-9b93-c3c3a8e3d36a
                  287e690e-0a47-4459-a0bb-be36fe439068`

Comment: There are multiple occurrences of the ids pattern in the second line. You could match them from group 7 afterwards `\b[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird using your method i get this
https://regex101.com/r/LJnVrS/101

Comment: I think I meant the same as what Wiktor suggested by first getting the value from group7 and then afterwards running a re.findall using that pattern to get the occurrences you are looking for. https://regex101.com/r/WI9hFd/1

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\dZ)\s+(INFO|WARN|DEBUG|ERROR|FATAL|TRACE)\s+(.*?\s+.*?)(.*?)\-\s+(.*?)\s+(?:(\[?.*?\])?)(.*?\s+(?<id1>[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\s+(\w+\s+)*(?<id2>[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(\s+\w*)*)
```

I have made the following changes:

1. For the id patterns, instead of `.*-.*-.*-.*-.*`, I have used `[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.
2. The id patterns are named groups - `id1` and `id2`. **So, you will need to get them by these names instead of the group numbers.** This helps in that even if there is a change to the regex anywhere else, your group reference doesn't have to change. These groups will have the ids, if they are present in the log line.
3. I have used `\w+` instead of `.*` where applicable.

Log lines 1 and 3 do not find anything (even earlier). I have not tried to resolve that.

**Note:** If you are using Ruby 2+ or Perl, the id pattern may be reused as a subroutine instead of being repeated entirely. That will increase readability.